# Finding 2 vectors knowing their cross product and one constraint

Tags: math, vector, 3d, linear-algebra

I have to find two vectors in 3D space, `a` and `b` such `a x b = c` where `c` is known. I also know one constraint, let's say that `a_y = 0`
So I have to look for these 2 vectors on `(c_x)x+(c_y)y+(c_z)z=0` plane, for vector `a` I can simplify it to `(c_x)x+(c_z)z=0`
for vector `b` since it's perpendicular to `a` as well it has to be in intersection of `(a_x)x+(a_z)z=0` plane and `(c_x)x+(c_y)y+(c_z)z=0` plane. 
After adding cross product equation to that I have `4` equations and `5` unknowns `(a_x,a_z,b_x,b_y,b_z)`. How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Maybe explaining what I need these for will help out somehow.
I have camera direction vector and I need vector that points to the right of screen, and second one that points up.

Comment: Adding an assumption on the length of a (like a_x^2+a_z^2 = 1) should do it.

Comment: @JohnMoeller I agree ... I based my answer on it and math properties of the vectors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **problem definition**

   ```
   A,B=?
   C=!
   Ay=!
   A x B = C
   ```

   implicated properties of dot and cross  product due to perpendicularity:

   ```
   (A.C) = 0
   (B.C) = 0
   |A|.|B| = |C|
   ```
2. **set `length` for one of the vectors to any known constant like `1`**

   ```
   |A|=1
   |B|=|C|
   ```

   This is also mentioned by **John Moeller** in his comment
3. **Compute `A`**

   So length of `|A|=1` and dot product of `(A.C)=0` as they are perpendicular so:

   ```
       Ax^2 + Ay^2 + Az^2 = 1
       Ax.Cx + Ay.Cy + Az.Cz = 0
   ```

   This is system of `2` equations and `2` unknowns so solve it. It will lead to `2` solutions chose one that is nonzero.
4. **Compute `B`**

   We know that `B` is perpendicular to `C` so `(B.C)=0` so put the constrains together:

   ```
   A x B = C
   Bx.Cx + By.Cy + Bz.Cz = 0
   Bx^2 + By^2 + Bz^2 = Cx^2 + Cy^2 + Cz^2
   ```

   If you expand the cross product you will get `5` equations and `3` unknowns. So solve the system (chose any `3` of the non trivial equations).

**PS It seems this is to generate your NEH matrix analogy**

So if that is the case all 3 vectors are perpendicular to each other while one points to specific direction (`Up` or `North` ...) and the sizes are usually `1` for all vectors.

So let assume `D` vector is the known aligning vector:

```
A'= C x D
B = C x A'
A = C x B
```

You can change the order of operands to obtain the directions you need. If the `D` is not known then you can use `(1,0,0)` or `(0,1,0)` or `(0,0,1)` instead chose one that is non parallel with `C` ... or have biggest `(C.D)`. Also take a look at:

- [How to find view point coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862519/2521214)

**[Notes]**

dot product: `(A.B)=Ax.Bx+Ay.By+Az.Cz`
cross product: `A x B`
length: `|A| = sqrt (Ax^2 + Ay^2 + Az^2)`