# Azimuth and Elevation from one moving object to another, relative to first object's orientation

Tags: matlab, math, 3d, quaternions, coordinate-transformation

I have two moving objects with position and orientation data (Euler Angles, Quaternions) relative to ECI coordinate frame.  I would like to calculate AZ/EL from what I'm guessing is the "body frame" of the first object.  I have attempted to convert both objects into the body frame through rotation matrices (X-Y-Z and Z-Y-X rotation sequence) and calculate a target vector AZ/EL this way but have not had success.  I've also tried to get body frame positions and calculate the body axis/angles and convert back to Eulers (relative to body frame).  I'm never sure how the coordinate system axes I'm supposedly creating are aligned along my object.

I have found a couple other questions like this answered with Quaternion solutions so that may be the best path to take, however my Quaternion background is weak at best and I fail to see how the computations given result in a target vector.

Any advice would be much appreciated and I'm happy to share my progress/experiences going forward.

Comment: Would something like [this](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/aerotbx/ug/quat2angle.html) help? If you dont have the Aerospace Toolbox, you can find similar functions online easily.

Comment: I believe that would help if I had a quaternion relative to body frame between the two objects.  Is something like that easily calculable?

Answer (score 1):

1. **get the current NEH transform matrix for the moving object**

   you **must** know position and at least two directions from **North,East,Height(Up or Altitude)** of the moving object otherwise is your problem **unsolvable** no matter what. This matrix/frame is called **NEH (X=North,Y=East,Z=Height)** or sometimes also **ENU (X=East,Y=North,Z=Up)**. Look here [transform matrix anatomy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216549/2521214) and here [Earth's NEH construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25433965/2521214) and change the position and radius to match your moving object.
2. **convert point P0 from GCS (global coordinate system) to NEH**

   simply: `P1=Inverse(NEH)*P0` where `P1` is now in **NEH** LCS (Local coordinate system). Both `P0,P1` are in homogenous coordinates `{ x,y,z,w=1 }` to allow multiplications with `4x4` matrix so you can compute azimut and elevation directly from it:

   [image: NEH vs. Azimutal coordinates]

   - `Azimut=atanxy(P1.x,P1.y);`
   - `Elevation=atan(P1.z/sqrt((P1.x*P1.x)+(P1.y*P1.y)));`

   where [atanxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697187/2521214) is mine `atan2` (4 quadrant `atan`) first is `dx` then `dy`. I think `atan2` in matlab has it in reverse.

**[Notes]**

Always visually check all frames (especially **NEH**). Just draw the 3 axises as lines of some length to validate if the result is correct. It should look like on image, just different color for each axis. **You can move to next point only if NEH is OK !!!**

Check `atan2/atanxy` operands order and also check goniometric functions units (`rad,deg`) to avoid confusions.